# How do I remove a new file that was committed to HEAD

Tags: git

I have added couple of new files and committed to the HEAD. These 2 files are not required and I would like to remove them completely.

`git status` shows the following

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/adurai/istio-config' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .idea/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Below is the output of `git show --stat --oneline HEAD` -

Output

```
bf3b6dc (HEAD -> adurai/config) Add base istio configurations
 terraform/platform/istio/common/istio-config/a.yaml                 | 13 +++++++++++++
 terraform/platform/istio/common/istio-config/b.yaml                 | 36 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 terraform/platform/istio/common/istio-config/templates/gateway.yaml |  4 ++--
 terraform/platform/istio/common/istio-uninstall.sh                  |  2 +-
 4 files changed, 52 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

a.yaml and b.yaml files are not supposed to be pushed. These are new files. How do I remove them ?

I already tried `git reset HEAD ./terraform/platform/istio/common/istio-config/a.yaml` but of no help.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove them:

```
git rm a.yaml b.yaml
```

And then amend your latest commit:

```
git commit --amend
```